How to share a matrix in shared memory across multiple users using R/bigmemory
I have a matrix in shared memory that I want to access (read-only) by multiple users using R/bigmemory. Is it possible and how? I tried to change the rights of the files in shared memory, but it's not really working because of mutexes. I am not a shared memory expert and warmly welcome your help. This is what I have tried out so far.
Put matrix into shared memory with user x
library(bigmemory)

# Create matrix
m = matrix(1:1000, nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
tmp = tempfile()
fwrite(m, tmp, sep = "\t", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

# Load into shared memory
big.matrix = read.big.matrix(tmp, type='double', shared = TRUE, header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
signature = describe(big.matrix)
dput(signature, "test.signature")

# Give R/W rights to group as well
sh_files = Sys.glob(file.path("/dev/shm/", paste0(signature@description$sharedName, "*")))
sapply(sh_files, Sys.chmod, mode = "664")

Matrix-related Files created in shared memory:

04477daf-c2f3-4364-94d8-7326b83fa92c
04477daf-c2f3-4364-94d8-7326b83fa92c_counter

Change to user y (belongs to same group) and access matrix in shared memory
library(bigmemory)
sig = dget("test.signature")
m = attach.big.matrix(sig)

It works fine. New file is created in shared memory with 644 rights:

sem.04477daf-c2f3-4364-94d8-7326b83fa92c_bigmemory_counter_mutex

Now, when switch back to user x and try to attach the matrix, I get this error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception'
  what():  Permission denied
Aborted

I suppose it's because of the mutex file. The error disappears when I delete it or change rights to 664. But only until I access it again with user y when a new mutex file is created.
